# AutoScroll при поиске в DataGridView (WinForms)

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net

У меня в гриде показываются данные из БД, и когда я делаю поиск по номеру `ID`, то соответствующая строка помечается в списке зеленым цветом, но когда эта строка находится не в видимой части грида, то не делается  **AutoScroll**, чтобы показать строку, а только помечает.

Как написать код для **AutoScroll**, чтобы помечал строку и сразу же показал??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В подобных ситуациях обычно помогает свойство `CurrentCell` у грида.
Возьмите любую ячейку из найденной строки и назначьте её этому свойству. Тогда грид автоматически "перемотает" таблицу в нужное место.

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[i, j];
```

i-номер колонки;

j-номер найденной строки.